# ObjLoader issue

Tags: object, webgl

I coded an .obj file loader for my webgl project. For the moment it is very simple.It manages to load relatively simple templates but I can't manage to load the stanford dragon. The output doesn't work at all. Here is a picture of the result. I'm really lost because my code seems to be correct. However, I don't have much experience with .obj files and something must be wrong

I really appreciate if someone can help me and tell me what's not working.

This is the link to the github repo : https://github.com/francois141/WebGlEngine

This is the code for the OBJ Loader class :

```
class CubeObj {

constructor(gl) {
    this.gl = gl;
    this.object = {};

    this.object.texte = `add OBJ file here`;
    
    this.object.numIndices = 0;

    this.vertexData = [0, 0, 0];
    this.textureCoords = [0, 0];
    this.vertexNormals = [0, 0, 0];
    this.vertexIndices = [];

    this.vData = [0, 0, 0];
    this.tCoords = [0, 0];
    this.vNormals = [0, 0, 0];

    this.positionBuffer = null;
    this.indicesBuffer = null;
    this.normalesBuffer = null;
    this.textureBuffer = null;

    this.processObject();
    this.computeBuffers();
}

getSize() {
    return this.object.numIndices;
}

processObject() {

    var data = this.object.texte.trim().split('\n');
    data = data.map(n => n.trim());

    data.forEach((string) => {
        if (string.startsWith('v ')) {
            let line = string.split(' ');
            this.vData.push(parseFloat(line[1]), parseFloat(line[2]), parseFloat(line[3]));
        }
        else if (string.startsWith('vt ')) {
            let line = string.split(' ');
            this.tCoords.push(parseFloat(line[1]), parseFloat(line[2]));
        }
        else if (string.startsWith('vn ')) {
            let line = string.split(' ');
            this.vNormals.push(parseFloat(line[1]), parseFloat(line[2]), parseFloat(line[3]));
        }
        else if (string.startsWith('f ')) {

            this.vertexIndices.push(++this.object.numIndices);
            this.vertexIndices.push(++this.object.numIndices);
            this.vertexIndices.push(++this.object.numIndices);

            let index1 = string.split(' ')[1]
            let index2 = string.split(' ')[2]
            let index3 = string.split(' ')[3]

            this.processVertex(index1);
            this.processVertex(index2);
            this.processVertex(index3);
        }
    });
}

processVertex(index) {

    let vertexIndex = 3 * parseInt(index.split('/')[0]);
    let textureIndex = 2 * parseInt(index.split('/')[1]);
    let normalIndex = 3 * parseInt(index.split('/')[2]);

    this.vertexData.push(this.vData[vertexIndex]);
    this.vertexData.push(this.vData[vertexIndex + 1]);
    this.vertexData.push(this.vData[vertexIndex + 2]);

    this.textureCoords.push(this.tCoords[textureIndex]);
    this.textureCoords.push(this.tCoords[textureIndex + 1]);

    this.vertexNormals.push(this.vNormals[normalIndex]);
    this.vertexNormals.push(this.vNormals[normalIndex + 1]);
    this.vertexNormals.push(this.vNormals[normalIndex + 2]);
}

computeBuffers = () => {

    this.positionBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer();
    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.positionBuffer);
    this.gl.bufferData(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(this.vertexData), this.gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    this.indicesBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer();
    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.indicesBuffer);
    this.gl.bufferData(this.gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(this.vertexIndices), this.gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    this.normalesBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer();
    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.normalesBuffer);
    this.gl.bufferData(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(this.vertexNormals), this.gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    this.textureBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer();
    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.textureBuffer);
    this.gl.bufferData(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(this.textureCoords), this.gl.STATIC_DRAW);

}


getBuffers = () => {
    return {
        position: this.positionBuffer,
        indices: this.indicesBuffer,
        normales: this.normalesBuffer,
        textureCoords: this.textureBuffer,
    }
}
```

[image: Loading the obj file]

Have a nice day.

François

Comment: I think there is a problem because the file is too big. When i reduce the number of f lines, everything is correct. However as soon as I increase the number of f line it produces this output

Comment: how many indices are there when you finish? The max in WebGL1 is 65536. (0 to 65535). You can switch to `UNSIGNED_INT` indices but you need to check for and enable the [int indices extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_element_index_uint/). On the other hand, given the loader is not trying to share any vertices there's no reason to even have indices. Just use `drawArrays`

Comment: Using drawArrays [it works](https://jsgist.org/?src=586cc018577ff30616795e5e4e9954c5)

Answer (score 0):

To figure this out I wrote a quick emu of the WebGL functions the code is using, just enough to use run the code as is and see the results. Of course I could have just looked at it in the debugger.

```
gl = {
  createBuffer() { return []; },
  bindBuffer(t, b) { this.b = b; },
  bufferData(t, d, h) { this.b.splice(0, this.b.length, ...d); },
};
```

Then I grabbed a cube .obj file to start with something where it's each to check every detail.

I ran it like this

```
const c = new CubeObj(gl);
console.log(c.getBuffers());
```

Which resulted in

[image]

We know a cube should have 36 indices but there are only 18.

The issue is that the `f` lines can have more than 3 vertices.

I changed the code to this

```
 } else if (string.startsWith('f ')) {

    let verts = string.split(' ').slice(1);
    const numTriangles = verts.length - 2;
    for (let i = 0; i < numTriangles; ++i) {
      this.vertexIndices.push(++this.object.numIndices);
      this.vertexIndices.push(++this.object.numIndices);
      this.vertexIndices.push(++this.object.numIndices);
      this.processVertex(verts[0]);
      this.processVertex(verts[i + 1]);
      this.processVertex(verts[i + 2]);
    }
  }
```

which seems to work

```js
const obj = `
# Blender v2.80 (sub 75) OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
mtllib cube.mtl
o Cube
v 1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
vt 0.375000 0.000000
vt 0.625000 0.000000
vt 0.625000 0.250000
vt 0.375000 0.250000
vt 0.375000 0.250000
vt 0.625000 0.250000
vt 0.625000 0.500000
vt 0.375000 0.500000
vt 0.625000 0.750000
vt 0.375000 0.750000
vt 0.625000 0.750000
vt 0.625000 1.000000
vt 0.375000 1.000000
vt 0.125000 0.500000
vt 0.375000 0.500000
vt 0.375000 0.750000
vt 0.125000 0.750000
vt 0.625000 0.500000
vt 0.875000 0.500000
vt 0.875000 0.750000
vn 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 0.0000 1.0000
vn -1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 -1.0000 0.0000
vn 1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 0.0000 -1.0000
usemtl Material
s off
f 1/1/1 5/2/1 7/3/1 3/4/1
f 4/5/2 3/6/2 7/7/2 8/8/2
f 8/8/3 7/7/3 5/9/3 6/10/3
f 6/10/4 2/11/4 4/12/4 8/13/4
f 2/14/5 1/15/5 3/16/5 4/17/5
f 6/18/6 5/19/6 1/20/6 2/11/6
`;

class CubeObj {

  constructor(gl) {
    this.gl = gl;
    this.object = {};

    this.object.texte = obj;

    this.object.numIndices = 0;

    this.vertexData = [0, 0, 0];
    this.textureCoords = [0, 0];
    this.vertexNormals = [0, 0, 0];
    this.vertexIndices = [];

    this.vData = [0, 0, 0];
    this.tCoords = [0, 0];
    this.vNormals = [0, 0, 0];

    this.positionBuffer = null;
    this.indicesBuffer = null;
    this.normalesBuffer = null;
    this.textureBuffer = null;

    this.processObject();
    this.computeBuffers();
  }

  getSize() {
    return this.object.numIndices;
  }

  processObject() {

    var data = this.object.texte.trim().split('\n');
    data = data.map(n => n.trim());

    data.forEach((string) => {
      if (string.startsWith('v ')) {
        let line = string.split(' ');
        this.vData.push(parseFloat(line[1]), parseFloat(line[2]), parseFloat(line[3]));
      } else if (string.startsWith('vt ')) {
        let line = string.split(' ');
        this.tCoords.push(parseFloat(line[1]), parseFloat(line[2]));
      } else if (string.startsWith('vn ')) {
        let line = string.split(' ');
        this.vNormals.push(parseFloat(line[1]), parseFloat(line[2]), parseFloat(line[3]));
      } else if (string.startsWith('f ')) {

        let verts = string.split(' ').slice(1);
        const numTriangles = verts.length - 2;
        for (let i = 0; i < numTriangles; ++i) {
          this.vertexIndices.push(++this.object.numIndices);
          this.vertexIndices.push(++this.object.numIndices);
          this.vertexIndices.push(++this.object.numIndices);
          this.processVertex(verts[0]);
          this.processVertex(verts[i + 1]);
          this.processVertex(verts[i + 2]);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  processVertex(index) {

    let vertexIndex = 3 * parseInt(index.split('/')[0]);
    let textureIndex = 2 * parseInt(index.split('/')[1]);
    let normalIndex = 3 * parseInt(index.split('/')[2]);

    this.vertexData.push(this.vData[vertexIndex]);
    this.vertexData.push(this.vData[vertexIndex + 1]);
    this.vertexData.push(this.vData[vertexIndex + 2]);

    this.textureCoords.push(this.tCoords[textureIndex]);
    this.textureCoords.push(this.tCoords[textureIndex + 1]);

    this.vertexNormals.push(this.vNormals[normalIndex]);
    this.vertexNormals.push(this.vNormals[normalIndex + 1]);
    this.vertexNormals.push(this.vNormals[normalIndex + 2]);
  }

  computeBuffers = () => {

    this.positionBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer();
    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.positionBuffer);
    this.gl.bufferData(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(this.vertexData), this.gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    this.indicesBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer();
    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.indicesBuffer);
    this.gl.bufferData(this.gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(this.vertexIndices), this.gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    this.normalesBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer();
    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.normalesBuffer);
    this.gl.bufferData(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(this.vertexNormals), this.gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    this.textureBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer();
    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.textureBuffer);
    this.gl.bufferData(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(this.textureCoords), this.gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  }


  getBuffers = () => {
    return {
      position: this.positionBuffer,
      indices: this.indicesBuffer,
      normales: this.normalesBuffer,
      textureCoords: this.textureBuffer,
    }
  }
}

gl = {
  createBuffer() {
    return [];
  },
  bindBuffer(t, b) {
    this.b = b;
  },
  bufferData(t, d, h) {
    this.b.splice(0, this.b.length, ...d);
  },
};

const c = new CubeObj(gl);
const buffers = c.getBuffers();

const m4 = twgl.m4;
const ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');

function render(time) {
  const clock = time * 0.001;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(ctx.canvas.width / 2, ctx.canvas.height / 2);
  ctx.scale(ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  ctx.lineWidth = 1 / ctx.canvas.width;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";

  const fieldOfView = Math.PI * 0.25;
  const aspect = ctx.canvas.clientWidth / ctx.canvas.clientHeight;
  const projection = m4.perspective(fieldOfView, aspect, 0.01, 5);
  const radius = 8;
  const eye = [
    Math.sin(clock) * radius, -2,
    Math.cos(clock) * radius
  ];
  const target = [0, 0, 0];
  const up = [0, 1, 0];
  const camera = m4.lookAt(eye, target, up);
  const view = m4.inverse(camera);

  const worldViewProjection = m4.multiply(projection, view);

  drawLines(buffers.position, buffers.indices, worldViewProjection);
  ctx.restore();
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);

function drawLines(cubeVertices, indices, worldViewProjection) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  // transform points
  const points = [];
  for (var ii = 0; ii < cubeVertices.length; ii += 3) {
    points.push(m4.transformPoint(
      worldViewProjection, [cubeVertices[ii + 0], cubeVertices[ii + 1], cubeVertices[ii + 2]]));
  }
  for (var ii = 0; ii < indices.length; ii += 3) {
    var p0 = points[indices[ii + 0]];
    var p1 = points[indices[ii + 1]];
    var p2 = points[indices[ii + 2]];
    ctx.moveTo(p0[0], p0[1]);
    ctx.lineTo(p1[0], p1[1]);
    ctx.lineTo(p2[0], p2[1]);
    ctx.lineTo(p0[0], p0[1]);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
```

You might find [this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-load-obj.html) useful as a reference.

Also in the future, posting a runnable [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) would be super helpful

---

So the issue is your dragon as 300000 vertices but using indexed vertices WebGL, by default, can only handle 65536 vertices (Uint16). You can either check for and enable `OES_index_element_uint` to enable using 32bit indices. OR, you can just not use indices since the loader is just treating every vertex as unique. OR, you can try to split the model in to chunks that use no more than 65536 vertices each.

Comment: Thank you for your help !

I know that a line that starts with a f can have more than 3 vertices. However the dragon model has only 3 vertices after a 'f '. Something else must be wrong in my obj loader but I don't know what it is.

If anyone has an idea, I would appreciate the help

Comment: did you read the article linked and see if it mentions anything you're doing differently?

Comment: Yes I read the article and the code loaded correctly the dragon. I will try to find what is wrong. Thank you for your help

Comment: I don't have your dragon but I did try loading the chair from the article with the code in the answer above and [it worked for that](https://jsgist.org/?src=11bd97351e0b89435e9a751363c3b624)

Comment: You can find the dragon here :  https://github.com/francois141/WebGlEngine/blob/master/models/object.obj I think the chair is not big enough since it also worked for me